# .htaccess rewrite query string as path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched for this question but I only come across really specific answers that seem difficult to tailor to my specific needs.

Let's say the URL I'm attempting to rewrite is this:

```
http://www.example.org/test.php?whatever=something
```

I want to rewrite it so that it appears as this:

```
http://www.example.org/test/something
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Here are some examples: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to route a request like `/test/something` to internally rewrite so that the content at `/test.php?whatever=something` gets served, you would use these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*?)/?$ /test.php?whatever=$1 [L]
```

And in order to redirect the query string URL to the nicer looking one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php\?whatever=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?test\.php$ /test/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If by using above code if someone having issue in trailing query string then they just need to add trailing question mark at end of the last rule, here is a updated code 

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /test\.php\?whatever=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?test\.php$ /test/%1? [L,R=301]`

Comment: i have use the same rules but its not working my url is http://example.com/directory1/directory2/login.php?id=8 and i want to make it like http://example.com/directory1/directory2/login/8 please tell me how to fix it