# URL Rewriting confusion

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I got a webpage that has the following URL:

```
localhost/Minecraft-User-Info/player/?user=matthijs110
```

Now I want it to `localhost/Minecraft-User-Info/player/matthijs110`

So without `?user=matthijs110`

I tried different ways, but it doesn't seem to work. Mod_Rewrite is enabled.

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path

Comment: what directory is your htaccess in?

Comment: Root, so where my main index.php is (Minecraft-User-Info folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Minecraft-User-Info/player/(.+)$ /Minecraft-User-Info/player/?user=$1 [L]
```

Edit:
Use this since it's in a sub directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Minecraft-User-Info/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^player/(.+)$ player/?user=$1 [L]
```

Updated to show my original answer and included the edit per users comment about where htaccess is located.

Comment: Ok then try adding the RewriteBase since your htaccess file is in the `Minecraft-User-Info` directory. And try it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. `Minecraft-User-Info/player/username` Redirects to `Minecraft-User-Info/player/index.php?user=username`
Tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ instead of setting up my own server for it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Minecraft-User-Info/player/(.+)$ /Minecraft-User-Info/player/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^Minecraft-User-Info/player/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\$ index.php?playerId=$1
```

Comment: well so in the index.php you have to define the template for the particular playerId you are parsing do you?

Comment: did you check you are getting the player id index.php? bcz this way we are getting request through index

Comment: @GayanChathuranga that's not what he asked for. He's not using a friendly link that ends in html. This is will not work for what he's asking for.