# Red alert [AWS]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In a nutshell, I want to be able to use htaccess so that I can execute various rewritte commands. I am using AWS elasticbeanstalk, and below is my dilemna when trying to get htaccess to work.

My instance have failed to be uploaded, and have received a red alert has shown in the image below:
[image]

Essentially I have overwrite all using .ebextensions to allow htaccess to work with the following code:

```
files:          
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf": 
     mode: "644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       AllowOverride All
```

but that's not whats causing problem. what runs problem is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

located in htaccess. almost like it cant accept rewritenegine being turned on.

Update:

In /var/log/eb-activity.log:

```
Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded.
[2015-07-10T10:25:09.784Z] INFO  [25589] - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-07-10T10:25:10.206Z] INFO  [25589] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-07-10T10:25:10.207Z] INFO  [25589] - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-07-10T10:25:10.207Z] INFO  [25589] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2015-07-10T10:25:10.207Z] INFO  [25589] - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
```

In /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log

```
   [2015-07-10T10:37:19.644Z] DEBUG [25873] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] DEBUG [25873] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-80bbbd77)..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] INFO  [25873] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-80bbbd77)..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] DEBUG [25873] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] INFO  [25873] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] INFO  [25873] : Command processor should execute command.
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] DEBUG [25873] : Storing current stage..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.645Z] DEBUG [25873] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.646Z] INFO  [25873] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.646Z] DEBUG [25873] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2015-07-10T10:37:19.647Z] DEBUG [25873] : Refreshing metadata..
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.061Z] DEBUG [25873] : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.061Z] DEBUG [25873] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.062Z] DEBUG [25873] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.064Z] INFO  [25873] : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.066Z] INFO  [25873] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.066Z] DEBUG [25873] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.066Z] INFO  [25873] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.066Z] DEBUG [25873] : Setting environment variables..
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.066Z] INFO  [25873] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.067Z] DEBUG [25873] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.067Z] INFO  [25873] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.067Z] DEBUG [25873] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2015-07-10T10:37:20.067Z] INFO  [25873] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

update3 the content of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /searchPage.php\?crs_category=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$  searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: I suggest you log into the instance and see what the nginx logs say

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `AllowOverride` is valid only in `<Directory>` sections specified
>   without regular expressions, not in `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>`
>   or `<Files>` sections.
>
> Source: [Apache Core Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

You put the `AllowOverride` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf`. It might cause the Apache failed to start.

I've just tried using default Elastic Beanstalk Sample PHP configuration (see [Supported Platforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.PHP) and [Sample Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html#RelatedResources-sampleapps)). I also add two new files into sample PHP app:

**`phpinfo.php`**

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?info.html$ phpinfo.php [L]
```

The result is:

[image: PHPInfo was displayed correctly using <code>mod_rewrite</code> /info.html]

By default, Elastic Beanstalk PHP environment already enable the `mod_rewrite` and `AllowOverride All` to the PHP app directory.

I've also tried to add your `.ebextensions` script (add).

> ```
> files:             "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf": 
>      mode: "644"
>      owner: root
>      group: root
>      content: |
>        AllowOverride All
> ```

After it was deployed, the Apache server failed to start and I could not access the web. This was caused by wrong config. The error was that I've ever said in top of my answer.

The solution might be by removing your `enable_mod_rewrite.conf` and use the default environment.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use a simple `searchPage.php` and your `.htaccess`, but with a bit modified, you had an extra space between `^` and `category` in 2nd line.

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} searchPage.php\?crs_category=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/$1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ searchPage.php?crs_category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

**`searchPage.php`**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    print_r($_SERVER);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
```

I tried to do a curl:

```
$ curl -v 'http://default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com/searchPage.php?crs_category=test'

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.173.237.116...
* Connected to default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com (54.173.237.116) port 80 (#0)
> GET /searchPage.php?crs_category=test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 13:27:56 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 1490
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
Array
(
    [PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT] => 256M
    [PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME] => 60
    [PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS] => Off
    [PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS] => 
    [PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN] => On
    [PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION] => Off
    [PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /
    [PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE] => UTC
    [HTTP_HOST] => default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => curl/7.35.0
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 149.129.122.128
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 80
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_NAME] => default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 172.31.5.238
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 172.31.30.235
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/searchPage.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 24890
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => crs_category=test
    [REQUEST_URI] => /searchPage.php?crs_category=test
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /searchPage.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /searchPage.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1437485276.635
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1437485276
)
Array
(
    [crs_category] => test
)
* Connection #0 to host default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com left intact
```

and

```
$ curl -v 'http://default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com/category/test'                   

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.5.119.104...
* Connected to default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com (52.5.119.104) port 80 (#0)
> GET /category/test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 13:30:13 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 1918
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT] => 256M
    [REDIRECT_PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME] => 60
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS] => Off
    [REDIRECT_PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS] => 
    [REDIRECT_PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN] => On
    [REDIRECT_PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION] => Off
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE] => UTC
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT] => 256M
    [PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME] => 60
    [PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS] => Off
    [PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS] => 
    [PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN] => On
    [PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION] => Off
    [PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /
    [PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE] => UTC
    [HTTP_HOST] => default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => curl/7.35.0
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 149.129.122.128
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT] => 80
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_NAME] => default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 172.31.5.238
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 172.31.11.66
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/searchPage.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 16148
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => crs_category=test
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /category/test
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => crs_category=test
    [REQUEST_URI] => /category/test
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /searchPage.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /searchPage.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1437485413.02
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1437485413
)
Array
(
    [crs_category] => test
)
* Connection #0 to host default-environment-zjqxqumicq.elasticbeanstalk.com left intact
```

It's worked.

Comment: thank you for your response and yes the response you receive after you deploy it with the config file is precisely what I get (the Apache server failed to start and I could not access the web.) if htaccess is enabled by default, my question is how come it doesnt work because it works fine in localhost. I have include an update 3 section under my initial post that include the htaccess code. the .htaccess file is located at the root of the project

Comment: I thought you had an extra space in your `.htaccess`. Check on my updated  answer above.

Comment: could you kindly explain your search page? is the content you wrote inside merely for testing purposes or is it necessary to get it to work?

Comment: In `searchPage.php`, I only print out the `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` variable. You can look at my code above. I thought you don't need add special thing in the page. Just make sure the file is exist and don't make a redirect loop.

Comment: I suggest you to create another simple php app with `mod_rewrite` in a new Elastic Beanstalk environment. You can use my code above as a sample if you want.

Comment: Sometime, a new environment could solve our problem. Because, we forgot something that we have changed in the old environment.

Comment: thanks for staying along. i've been wrapping my head around this for a few weeks. I've create a new file with a searchPage.php and .htaccess file

Comment: and uploaded it as a zip for some reason it doesn't read the .htaccess file and get the following when i type category/business/ Not Found

The requested URL /category/business/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Could you access `/category/business`?

Comment: neither. how would i enable mod_rewrite WHILE creating the eb environemnt?

Comment: It's enabled by default. If you want to load Apache module, just use `LoadModule` directive by creating a file using `.ebextensions`. But, you can check your `phpinfo()` first as my example in `phpinfo.php` above. If you find there is `mod_rewrite` there, the `mod_rewrite` is already on.

Comment: yes precisely i would like to use LoadModule, could you kindly elaborate on that?

Comment: i've checked using phpinfo() and yes mod_rewrite  is part of the loaded module

Comment: Is there a `mod_rewrite` in phpinfo? Just to make sure, ssh to your EB EC2 instance and check the /etc/httpd/. Is the Apache config correct in there?

Comment: ngsyes there is a mod_rewrite in phpinfo. i have never manipulated eb ec2 instance apache config setti

Comment: sorry for this newbieness but how i check /etc/httpd/

Comment: If you don't change anything, it should be ok. Try to run this: https://github.com/edwardsamuel/aws-eb-php-mod-rewrite-sample. Please use a new EB environment.

Comment: I thought when you failed to access `/category/business/` yesterday is caused by wrong zip format. When you open the zip file, it should be contain all your file (not a directory).

If you notice from my example, I asked you to access `http://<your-env-url>.elasticbeanstalk.com/aws-eb-php-mod-rewrite-sample-master/category/business/`. There is a directory `aws-eb-php-mod-rewrite-sample-master` when you open the [zip](https://github.com/edwardsamuel/aws-eb-php-mod-rewrite-sample/archive/master.zip) file.

Comment: thank you. your help has been tremendous and i appreciate the effort. One question and minor trouble i have is that it works when i type /category/business/ but i would like that when type searchPage.php?crs_category=business to be automatically rewritten (with an R=301 code to let search engine know). Also, why do i need to  Create this environment inside a VPC (it wasn't configure as such previously)

Comment: Look into this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path). I think it is same with you want.

Comment: Why use VPC instead of Classic environment? Take a look into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#differences-ec2-classic-vpc.