# How do I use the link to autofill information?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a php file that can be run when someone puts anything into a certain url. Say I want to go to a php script with $name as "david". Is it possible to go to a url www.-.com/Join/david and have it not go to that url, but rather a php script with a variable set to david?

Comment: Yes its possible but a little had with PHP, you can use PHP frameworks for that. Its called clean URL and for example; Laravel framework can be used to do that.

Comment: Yes, although it would be more along the lines of  you having a page called "Join.php" and it takes a querystring of `?name=david`. You'd have a rewrite rule of some sort in your `.htaccess` that makes `www.-.com/Join/david` *actually* be a URL mask for `join.php?name=david`.

Comment: Ok I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a page called `join.php` that takes a querystring, like `join.php?name=david`

With some rules in your `.htaccess` file, you could then use the url `/join/david/` to *actually* serve your `join.php?name=david` to the visitor.

The rules for this would be as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?join/(.*?)/?$ /join.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Additionally, you could add the following so that if anyone actually tries to go to `join.php?name=david`, they are redirected to the clean URL instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /join\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?join\.php$ /join/%1? [L,R=301]
```

**This answer references a [previous answer by Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003447/2026606) to a very similar question**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean url Method then you can get All Procedure from [Clean Url PHP Script](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/)

May be! Helpful to you :)
If any other Problem Please Provide Some Code and Description to make Better :)