# Php Rewrite Url .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, wamp

The problem I m facing that I am receiving an id from url and showing it simply

> http://localhost/test/?username=bingo123

Its working fine and shows the result

But I want that I should be able to write like

> http://localhost/test/bingo123 .

I tried to make `.htaccess` file and but it does not work and shows

> The requested URL /test/bingo123 was not found on this server

```
Rewriteengine on
Rewriterule ^([a-zA-z]+)$ index.php?username=$1
```

I want to know that what should i change make in `.htaccess` file or some other settings in Wamp to run the script and where should I save `.htaccess` so that It works fine .Here "test" the folder name where all php files are there and how to save the `.htaccess` file as it does not allow it to save without first name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite query string as path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]*)$ /test/?username=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Myabe Helpful

```
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+)$ test.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ test.php?username=$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ $ test.php?username=$1[L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)$ test.php?username=$1 [L]
```