# .htaccess rewrite query string as path url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I searched for this question but only came across very specific answers that I couldn't tailor to my requirements.

My URL now looks like this: `https://example.eu/?action=changepassword` and I want it to look like this: `https://example.eu/changepassword` so text `?action=` gets deleted.

[I tried to adapt this but it didn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, which url are you hitting in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I don't know if I understand the question correctly... but in the html code I have <a href> tag like this <a href="https://example.eu/?action=changepassword">.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules here....
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/?\?action=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to handle query string in backend.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?action=$1  [L]
```

Comment: This condition changed it to: https://example.eu/var/www/example.eu/changepassword

Comment: @Mazurky, where(on which path) is your htaccess file placed?

Comment: htaccess location: /var/www/example.eu/.htaccess
BUT
It's working now but I changed <a href> tag to: <a href="https://example.eu/changepassword">. I don't know if this is the right solution but it works. :D