# htaccess RewriteRule doesn't prettify my URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, s3-rewrite-rules

I have a Droplet on DigitalOcean, Ubuntu 22.04, SSL enabled, the site runs smoothly and `mod_rewrite` is on

Here's my `apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^getpro/([^/]*)$ /getpro.php?userID=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^play/([^/]*)$ /play.php?cID=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^subdetails/([^/]*)$ /subdetails.php?sub=$1 [NC,L]
```

None of those rules work, let's take the first one just as example, here's the original URL:

`https://example.com/profile.php?user=johndoe`

It should allow me to use: `https://example.com/profile/johndoe`, but it doesn't, this is what I get:

[image]

I've restarted apache, rebooted the server, waited for hours just to make sure the server  needed some time to process my changes, never got a positive result

PS: For instance, if I use this line for the profile redirect:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1`

and I call: `example.com/johndoe`, the redirect works.

So I don't understand why the redirect to the `profile.php` file doesn't work

Comment: Thai is strange, because it works on online [testing tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/). This is results of the test [https://prnt.sc/cv4CxJlAk2JA](https://prnt.sc/cv4CxJlAk2JA) You will see that I used your **input URL** `https://example.com/profile/johndoe` and **Output URL** is the same as yours `https://example.com/profile.php?user=johndoe `

Comment: "_mod_rewrite is on_" How do you check that? Do the other rules work?

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa I've tried that tool too, that's why I'm going crazy because my website doesn't work :(

Comment: @brombeer I simply run 'sudo a2enmod rewrite' and the terminal says 'Module rewrite already enabled'

Comment: Is that all in your `.htaccess` or is there more? Have you made sure that `.htaccess` is present and named correct in your folder? Nothing in your server logs? Do the other rules work?

Comment: I posted the 'apache2.conf' code too, the .htaccess name is correct and placed in the root of my server. Server logs say nothing about it, none of the rules in my htaccess file work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite query string as path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003319/htaccess-rewrite-query-string-as-path)

Comment: @FrankEno Try restarting your server `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: @MohammedJhosawa I did it 1000 times, that's the basic thing you must do every time you make an update, the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @FrankEno ".htaccess placed in the root of my server" which path is that? And to test try to remove all rules with `AllowOverride None`, and also check **virtual-host** file, because that rule can be places inside host block, like this [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/KRQKJVs9kVdJ)

Comment: Have you tried disabling `MultiViews`? That can often interfere in unwanted ways, when you have a partial overlap between your "fake" URLs, and physically existing script file names.